# ConEmu closes immediately

Tags: conemu

After deleting working (and quite old version of) Conemu from my laptop by mistake I tried to install it anew. But now, clicking on the icon, the window opens and immediately, in half a second, closes.

I tried to uninstall and install many times, different versions but all the time happens the same. Somewhere I've read that maybe the path in Settings is wrong but anyway I can't change it while it closes all the time.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case ConEmu doesn't wait if your shell (cmd, powershell, bash, etc.) closes immediately.
The simplest way to check what happens - run ConEmu from `Win+R`

```
ConEmu.exe -detached
```

Or, if that doesn't work

```
ConEmu.exe -basic -detached
```

And try to start shells from the new console dialog. Try simple cmd.exe first.
Than just configure your startup settings